# .NET 3.5, IIS 7, SQL Server 2008 hosting

Tags: iis-7, sql-server-2008, hosting, .net-3.5

Any recomendations on what services are out there to host an ASP.NET MVC application using .NET 3.5, IIS 7, SQL Server 2008? Any recommendation on shared? VPS? Dedicated?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirements about a month ago, and searched high and low for a balance of

- monthly price (10 bucks per was my target)
- ASP.NET + explicitly needing MVC
- not too pricey an add-on for SQL Server
- reputable company

I went for [DiscountASP.NET](http://discountasp.net/) They allow you to choose IIS7 or IIS6 when you're signing up.

Hint: find a coupon somewhere online. I remember seeing an advert in SQL Mag one day, as well as Code Mag. I successfully used the ['6 months free' code from CodeMag](http://discountasp.net/codemag/).

Comment: they are great, but remember only Shared Hosting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a greater degree of control over the environment, I would go with a Windows 2008 VPS (Hyper-V instance). Check out www.crystaltech.com. The prices are a bit high, but still cheaper than your own server, and better performance than Virtuozo based setups in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we are going with a dedicated server at [CariNet](http://cari.net).

Answer (score 0):

I went with Godaddy, $60 for a year and includes IIS7 and 2 SQL Databases (small tough).  It is great for testing.   SQL is 2005, don't know if they offer 2008.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy - look for one of their coupons and the price would drop to $41/year.

It's a shared server, IIS7, .Net 3.5, PHP 5 (if you need it), 1 SQL 2005 DB + 3 MySql DBs.

Their management interface is not great, but if you make your DB public (accessible to the world), you'll be able to manage it with SQL Management Studio (both 2005 and 2008 versions work).

They also provide a form mail service 9to send email from your ASP.Net pages) - but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for dedicated, check out www.serverloft.com . I used to have a VPS with serverintellect.com but it was too darn slow (disk read speeds would sometimes creep down to a few hundred kilobytes per second, i.e. floppy disk speeds) so I started looking for alternatives. After a bit of googling a stumbled over serverloft and I am now running Win2008 on a quad-core xeon box with 4Gb RAM and 250Gb disk (2x250Gb in Raid1) for $119 per month. Absolutely worth the price...  (so far at least :)  )